# result shows up without validation

Tags: php, html, regex

Im making a quiz/madlibs kind of site so for everything works but the validation. Whenever the user enters a special character or leaves the input field empty there should be a a warning and the submit button shouldn't be allowed to show the end result.

right now when i enter for example a "?" and after that press the submit button it will show the end result with all the answers.

what did i do wrong with my validation? how can i make it so you cant leave it empty and use special characters.

I check the validation with this code:

```
<?php
    $Input1 = $Input2 = $Input3 = $Input4 = $Input5 = $Input6 = $Input7 = "";
    $Input1Err = $Input2Err = $Input3Err = $Input4Err = $Input5Err = $Input6Err = $Input7Err = "";
    
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      if(empty($_POST["Input1"])){
        $Input1Err = "enter something.";
      }else{
        $Input1 = test_input($_POST["Input1"]);
        if(!preg_match("/[^a-z0-9 _]+$/i", $Input1)){
          $Input1Err = "only letters and white space allowed";
        }
      }
    
    
    function test_input($data) {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
    } ?>
```

for every input I made a validation like this:

```
      if(empty($_POST["Input1"])){
        $Input1Err = "enter something.";
      }else{
        $Input1 = test_input($_POST["Input1"]);
        if(!preg_match("/[^a-z0-9 _]+$/i", $Input1)){
          $Input1Err = "only letters and white space allowed";
        }
      }
```

and here is the full html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
   <title>Mad Libs</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Site.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text">Quiz game</h1>
<div class="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Quiz.php">quiz</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="POST">
        <h1> quiz</h1>
    
        <?php
            if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
                $Input1 = $_POST["Input1"];
                $Input2 = $_POST["Input2"];
                $Input3 = $_POST["Input3"];
                $Input4 = $_POST["Input4"];
                $Input5 = $_POST["Input5"];
                $Input6 = $_POST["Input6"];
                $Input7 = $_POST["Input7"];

                echo "Driving a car can be fun if you follow this $Input1. advice:
                When approaching a $Input2 on the right, always blow your $Input4 Before making a
                $Input3 turn, always stick your $Input2 out of the window.
                Every 2000 miles, have your  $Input1.inspected and your $Input5 checked.
                When approaching a school, watch out for  $Input6. 
               Above all, drive $Input6 the $Input7 you save may be your own!$Input2";
            
        ?>

        <?php }else{ ?>
        <p>Question.. <input type="text"  name="Input1" placeholder="enter here"></p> 


        <p>Question.. <input type="text"  name="Input2" placeholder="enter here"></p>

        <p>Question.. <input type="text"  name="Input3" placeholder="enter here"></p>

        <p>Question.. <input type="text"  name="Input4" placeholder="enter here"></p>

        <p>Question.. <input type="text"  name="Input5" placeholder="enter here"></p>

        <p>Question.. <input type="text"  name="Input6" placeholder="enter here"></p>

        <p>Question.. <input type="text"  name="Input7" placeholder="enter here"></p>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
    <?php } ?>

    <footer>
       <p>@2021.</p>
    </footer>
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So _where_ are you actually performing this validation? The code you have shown as “the full html” contains a form that submits to the same URL again - so where does the validation code even come into play here then?

Comment: I was about to say the same thing - the validation code appears to be unrelated to the rest of it. The "full" HTML+PHP you've shown doesn't include it, or call it at all.

Comment: the php block in the html is for showing the end result, the php outside of the html is for validating the input. with the form action i use that validation right?

Comment: With that form action, you are sending the submission to the same URL, that this document was initially requested from. And if _that_ script does not contain your validation code … well then the validation never happens.

Comment: Your form just posts back to the same URL it was loaded from - i.e. the same PHP script. It's unclear where the validation code is actually located. Is it in the same PHP file as the HTML? Please explain the context. You've shown it in your question as if it's separate. Even if it _is_ all in the same fie, all it does is populate an "error" variable. The rest of the code never actually checks that or displays it or uses it to decide what to do.

Comment: The validation code is in the same file as the html, above the html code block. i tried to call the function inside the sumbit button with:"input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" onclick="test_input()">

Comment: `test_input()` is a PHP function. But `onclick` is a JavaScript event - it can call JavaScript functions, not PHP functions. So that makes no sense at all.

Comment: can you explain how im supossed to call that function when the button is clicked? its in the same file so i thought it was already linked like that

Comment: `The validation code is in the same file as the html`...ok good start. But note what I said above - all your validation code does is populate `$Input1Err` if it finds an error. The rest of your code never actually does anything with that information. It doesn't display it, and it doesn't use it to decide whether to display the rest of the output.

Comment: `can you explain how im supossed to call that function when the button is clicked`...from PHP. It's a PHP function, so you can call it from other PHP code, if you need to. Submitting the form will start your PHP running (from the top of the script), so at that point your PHP code can call any PHP functions it wants to.

Comment: And you're already calling it here: `$Input1 = test_input($_POST["Input1"]);` anyway. So that's not an issue. Your issue is that the rest of your code is ignoring the results of your validation.

Comment: P.S. You would be better putting `$Input1Err`, `$Input2Err` etc into an array so you can easily loop through them later rather than hard-coding lots of individual checks on variables.

Comment: the code does show the answers when clicked on the button but it doesnt validate it. so when i put an php block like this <?php  function test_input() ?> inside the html it still doesnt work after the button click right

Comment: i get that the validation doesnt do anything with the rest of the code at this point but i dont really understand how to make it work with the other code together

Comment: You need some `if` statements later on to check the value of $Input1Err (and all the others - which is why you'd be better putting them in an array) and if they contain text then you need to display those errors and not display the "driving a car..." text. It's just an if/else situation.

Comment: Also all the bit lower down where you define `$Input1 = $_POST["Input1"];`, `$Input2 = $_POST["Input2"];` etc all over again is a) unnecessary and b) dangerous because it bypasses all the filtering you did in the test_input() function. So you can get rid of those 7 lines.

Comment: P.S. To go back to an earlier remark you made: `its in the same file so i thought it was already linked like that` ...no. Make sure you understand the difference between PHP and JavaScript, and the contexts in which they are executed. That's a separate piece of work for you to do after this.

Answer (score -1):

I think you dont have to validate if the input is text with spaces in the php. You could use the html input pattern attribute. For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="maininput">Input</label>
  <input type="text" id="maininput" name="maininput" pattern="[A-Za-z\s]+" title="Write Here your Error"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example the input only accepts letters and spaces. You could also add number with changing the pattern to [A-Za-z0-9\s]+.
Plus if you really want to keep using php to validate the input I think the wrong is the validation in the line `if(!preg_match("/[^a-z0-9 _]+$/i", $Input1)){`.

Comment: `if you really want to keep using php to validate`... to imply that the OP might stop doing this is bad and dangerous advice. Server-side validation isn't optional.  Client-side validation is optional. Server-side validation is mandatory. Client-side validation can enhance the user experience but can also easily be bypassed or disabled. Only server-side validation provides genuine protection. Also this answer doesn't address the causes of why the OP's server-side validation isn't fully working yet.